# Grid row size issue - changing size of row not reflected on screen

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

Okay, I've got a data template. Inside this data template I have a grid. This grid has two rows. When I resize the rows, I don't see an effect.

Just for you, I created a series of images to display the problem:

[Initial XAML of data template with no grid rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INTxf.jpg)

[What happens when the above XAML is run within application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpphY.jpg)

Hmm, well that border (with text box in) takes up the whole thing so we can't see the image. That's not good!

[Okay, let's change the code to have rows - XAML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zwobz.jpg) - nice half and half split.

[Here's that code put into the applocation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20G2O.jpg). All good so far. Nice half and half. But even still, I'd like it to take a bit less really. Maybe a quarter for the text box?

[Okay, so I've set it at a quarter for the text box in this XAML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhgwJ.jpg)

[And this should give me a nice one quarter border with text box right? Not exactly...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGb3e.jpg).

Anyone know what the heck is going on?

Thanks (and I hope you enjoyed the tour of images).